# Android: Use precompiled libraries?

Tags: android, performance

Every time I add a library to my Android project the compilation process gets slower. **Is there a way to cache the (library) dex files so only the application gets recompiled every time?** Ideally the build process should check whether the library JAR has changed, if it hasn't it should reuse the prexisting dex file.

I am using [nbandroid](http://www.nbandroid.org/) but I assume the Eclipse build suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build process (especially at dex step) in Android SDK (regardless of which IDE is in used) is quite inflexible. The only command usage of dx.jar AFAIK is something like below:

> [INFO] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\bin\java -Xmx1024M, -jar, C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\lib\dx.jar, --dex, --output=C:\workspace\myproject\target\classes.dex, C:\workspace\myproject\target\classes, C:\workspace\myproject\libs\common-lib.jar, ... ...

From here you can see that compiled classes with external jar libraries are dexed at project build time.

> **Is there a way to cache the (library) dex files so only the application gets recompiled every time?**

Jar libraries get dexed, not recompiled by Android SDK every time you build your project. I don't think Android SDK provide another command usage of dx.jar which you can use to dex only the complied class without external jar libraries then merged into the pre-existing classes.dex (perhaps generated from last time).

It is not possible at project build time, however, it is probably off topic but you may interested in this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) talked about dynamically loading jar libraries at runtime, worth to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse and have a few projects with 2-3MB of libraries, did not notice any slowdown except when compiling and signing final APK with proguard. Looks like Eclipse does not recompile libraries every time.

Comment: I am using the latest IDE and SDK and my external jars are always dx processed every single time I push the app to the device after updating my own source code.